# Are questions about exotic pets on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Do we want questions about exotic and unconventional pets such as tigers, lions, alligators, large snakes, etc?

Do we believe we have the expertise to answer questions about such animals?

Comment: Borderline, but I'll accept your view. Voted to close as well.

Comment: Heh -- the vet practice I go to has one vet who specializes in "exotics" -- by which they mean rabbits, lizards, ferrets, and assorted others.  When I saw the title I wasn't thinking lions and tigers and bears (oh my). :-)